# Mongo db timeout exception saying connection refused

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, spring-data-mongodb

Please Help me.
I am using mongo DB from a long time for a application.the application is in development mode. Sometimes I see this error

> ERROR-
>   Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]

But when I restart the server, it does not come again. But for once I have to restart the server. I am using mongodb 2.6.6.

Please help me. I am afraid of future because soon it will be on live mode.
my Databaseconnection class:

```
static final String mongoServer = Play.application().configuration().getString("application.mongo.db.server");
static final String mongoDBname = Play.application().configuration().getString("application.mongo.db.dbname");
static final String mongoUsername = Play.application().configuration().getString("application.mongo.db.username");
static final String mongoPassword = Play.application().configuration().getString("application.mongo.db.password");
static final int connectionPerHost = Play.application().configuration().getInt("application.mongo.db.connections");
static final int connectionIdleTime = Play.application().configuration().getInt("application.mongo.db.idletime");

private MongoTemplate _mongoTemplate;
private static MongoClient   _mongo;

public MongoTemplate getContext() {
    if(_mongoTemplate == null)
        openDbConnection();
    if(_mongo == null || _mongoTemplate == null)
        Logger.error("DatabaseConnection::openDbConnection - Unable to get context. How is this possible?");
    return _mongoTemplate;
}

private static synchronized void createMongo() {
    if(_mongo == null) {
        Logger.debug("DatabaseConnection::openDbConnection - Opening a new connection");
        MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().connectionsPerHost(connectionPerHost)
                .cursorFinalizerEnabled(true).maxConnectionIdleTime(connectionIdleTime).build();
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(mongoUsername, mongoDBname, mongoPassword.toCharArray());
        ServerAddress addr = null;
        try {
            addr = new ServerAddress(mongoServer);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Logger.error("Error Connecting to Mongo: Wrong Server??", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        _mongo = new MongoClient(addr, Arrays.asList(credential), options);
    }
}

private boolean openDbConnection() {
    try {
        if(_mongo == null) createMongo();
        // TODO: Connection Pooling
        _mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(_mongo, mongoDBname); //new MongoTemplate(dbFactory, converter);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error("Error Opening Connection:", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean closeDbConnection() {
    try {
        _mongoTemplate = null;
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.error("Error Closing", ex);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    closeDbConnection();
    super.finalize();
}
```

Comment: Odds are on that the answer is in your server logs so look there. The educated guess without seeing any code here is that you are probably exhausting the available connections. Something in your code is probably causing this by either creating more connections than you need or otherwise producing a heavy load without other pool management. Look at the server logs and your code for relevant connect information. StackOverflow is a "coding" Q&A site. So generally we need code to diagnose problems.

Comment: @neil lunn.i have posted my code ,thnx for suggestion

Comment: But did you get the point? The point was you are likely creating more connections than you need. This code does not seem to be necessary. The diver should handle a "connection pool" and your injection config should just make the connection available. It seems like the "rest of your code" not mentioned here actually makes the "connections" many times and never releases them. If you coded this part that way it seems that you are calling "connections" many times when you don't need to. That was my point. You need to look further and remove the redundant calls.

Comment: @ Neil lunn ok i need code for connection pooling also.i understand this .i will add the code ,can you please paste here link for that.it will be very helpful.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it appears when the monogdb connection is not established, verify it.